# Respond_with JSON @object sends associated objects, not @object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

How do I control the object that is returned in a .json request? I am getting the associated objects, not the main object--products, instead of company, in my example below:

```
class Company
  has_many :products
  include Enumerable

class Product
  belongs_to :company

controller Company
  respond_to :html, :json

  def show
    @company = Company.find(1)
    respond_with @company
  end

**respond_with @company   ==>  json of products, not company!**
respond_with @company.id ==> json of :id
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your controller?

Comment: @Robin I added the controller. I think I figured out that having Enumerable mixed in was causing the problem. Turns out that converting to JSON will retrieve the related collection of an enumerable object, rather than the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems with to_json on Rails, you'll get the associated collection of an object if it has a collection associated through **Enumerable**. In the question, if you remove the inclusion of Enumerable, the object returned in the json will be just that object. But with Enumerable included, the json results the full collection, in this case, products. To fix this, it seems that you have to remove Enumerable.